# Is that a good approch to manage hibernate session?

Tags: hibernate, session, dao

I am looking for a good way to manage hibernate session across web application.
My problem is that i dont want to allow session access in the view or API layer.
so i built the following method in my abstract BaseDao class.
the method method

```
protected static Session getSession() {
    if(!session.isOpen()){
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    }else{
        session.clear();
    }
    return session;
}
```

usage:

```
public IHibernateBean save(IHibernateBean bean) {
    Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
    getSession().saveOrUpdate(bean);
    t.commit();
    return bean;
}

public IHibernateBean getByPK(Class<?> class1 , Long pk) {
    IHibernateBean hibernateBean = (IHibernateBean) getSession().get( class1 , pk );
    return hibernateBean;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the contextual session obtained via `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`, see [2.3. Contextual sessions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/architecture.html#architecture-current-session).

Also see [Generic Data Access Objects](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/GenericDataAccessObjects) for example of typesafe DAO implementation.

Comment: @fatnjazzy: It's definitely not good since sessions are not getting closed. Using contextual sessions solves this problem by closing sessions implicitly.

Comment: If we close sessions, then on LAZY fetching, it gives error saying session is closed, how to solve that ?

Comment: Are you support contextual session for multi threaded environment?

Answer (score 0):

I'd echo axtavt's answer. Just as an additional information, if you are using a Java EE capable container (like JBoss AS), then use the EntityManager which is managed by it. It's specially easy in Java EE 6, with CDI.